# How to adjust a floating div based on its height and surroundings?

Tags: javascript, css

#### Disclaimer: The following code is using the [rubuxa](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/) plugin for JS sortables.

**Javascript:**

```
function qs(expr){return document.querySelector(expr)}
var container = qs('.ITEST');
var sort = Sortable.create(container, {
  animation: 350,
  draggable: ".draggable", 
});
```

**CSS:**

```
 .draggable{
    color: #fff;
    margin: 1px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block; 
}
.ITEST{
    width:425px;
    height:400px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid grey
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8o0upLq/9/

The problem lies when dragging the red squares, they move correctly, but they do not stack vertically ontop of each other but horizontally. This creates unwanted extra white space underneath. I have tried to set the same height for all divs, but with no luck.

Comment: I don't think this is possible just with CSS. Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294814/floated-divs-inside-a-div-has-bizarre-spacing

Comment: It's bounty time then!! My first one :). T minus 2 days.  Although, I'm still going to be fiddling with this on jsfiddle here for a while :P

Comment: So... let me see if I can get the question right. You want the 3 red squares to be displayed one below the other, and be able to change their position vertically, (and now here is the important part) between them, or between them and the rest of blocks (if is only between them you can do it, if is between them and the rest you can't)?

Comment: Basically zozo.  And yes whenever they are moved horizontally. Doesn't necessarily need to be between blocks, but they need to stack until they are at the height of the others or the whitespace starts to kick in. (That's the un-even part), I'm assuming though. Edit: [Check here](http://i.gyazo.com/f4e1fb55e773d3524fa51a1a832eb769.png) If you throw them in a corner it does the effect, but not when they're between divs, hmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just saw your post through Rubaxa's Github.

Anyways, there is no way you can achieve this with pure CSS. Even with Flexbox i can't think of a way you can do this.

For accomplish this behaviour you need some way of javascript to calculate absolute positioning.
The Library http://packery.metafizzy.co/ does a good job for this. It uses 'jQuery UI draggable' or 'Draggabilly' which uses absolute positioning.

The downside, i don't think there is a way to make this happen with Rubaxa's Sortable...